# How to playback a numpy array containing an audio signal by chunks?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, pyaudio

I want to process in real-time an audio file that is stored in a NumPy array while playing back the audio at the same time. I don't know how to set up the PyAudio so I can play audio while turning on and off some filters and a downsampling function. I am using this method to play from an array, but it plays the total array, not given chunks.

```
def play (signal, sr):    
    # Create an interface to PortAudio
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # Open a .Stream object to write the WAV file to
    # 'output = True' indicates that the sound will be played rather than recorded
    stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,
                    channels = 2,
                    rate = sr,
                    output = True,
                    output_device_index = 1)

    print("Playing quantized...")
    data = signal.astype(np.int16).tostring()
    stream.write(data)
    print("Stop playing.")
```

Comment: Ok, what's the problem? :)

Comment: I don't know how to setup the PyAudio so I can play audio while turning on and off some filters.

Comment: Maybe you should put that into your question then. Make it more specific.

Comment: I did it, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: No, personally I don't, but somebody else might. The problem is that your question is still too generic. You should show what kind of approach you tried so far, what specific problems you have, etc. Questions in the style of "please write this code for me" don't usually attract answers on Stack Overflow.